# ssh remote command using password-less sudo fails

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-keys, sudo

Logged on as bryan@localserver, I'm trying to perform a backup using rsync on a remote host bryan@remoteserver.

I need the rsync connection to elevate privileges on the remote host using `--rsync-path='sudo rsync'`, but I'm having problems, so have decided to simplify matters and just try to get the following working first:

```
bryan@localserver # ssh bryan@remoteserver 'sudo /usr/bin/whoami'
```

Once, I've cracked this, I should be able to get rsync working.

---

## What I've done so far:

I've got ssh configured so that bryan@localserver can ssh to bryan@remoteserver using key instead of a password.

```
bryan@localserver # ssh bryan@remoteserver
bryan@remoteserver #
```

I've also configured bryan@remoteserver to be able to run `/usr/bin/whoami` as sudo, without a password in the sudoers file on remoteserver:

```
bryan   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/whoami
```

This works fine:

```
bryan@remotehost # sudo whoami
root
```

But from the local server:

```
bryan@localhost # ssh bryan@remoteserver 'sudo /usr/bin/whoami'
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

My complete sudoers file (minus the comments and blank lines) is below:

```
Defaults env_reset
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
Defaults !requiretty
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
bryan   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/whoami
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

`ssh -t` from localserver solves the 'no tty present' error, but still prompts me for bryan@remotehost's password.

Can anyone please explain what the problem is?

localserver is Ubuntu 10.04 x64, remoteserver is Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you a member of the `sudo` group or `admin` group?  From the `sudoers` man page:

> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order. 
>   Where
>          there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not
>          necessarily the most specific match).

You can move your `bryan   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/whoami` line to the bottom so it is the last match.  This should keep you from being prompted for a password.